# Firestore's hasPendingWrites() returns false on deleted document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I have a registered a listener which listens to changes to a query. When a document is removed/deleted, it needs to check if the change was local or not. If the change is local, a message is displayed. If it was not local, the object is just removed.

The problem is that `hasPendingWrites()` returns `false` when checked in the listener. Why is that? According to Firestore docs, it should be `true` the first time as the listener is immediately triggered on alteration of the local cache.

Simplified code of AsyncArrayHandler, which is called when the listener is activated:

```
for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
{
    changeIsMadeLocal = documentChange.getDocument().getMetadata().hasPendingWrites();
    switch (documentChange.getType())
    {
        case REMOVED:
            if (changeIsMadeLocal)
            {
                //do stuff here
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think there's a bug in the SDK, you should send full reproduction instructions to Firebase support. It should contain *minimal* and *complete* code.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 4):

For everyone(and looking at the views, that's almost no one)running into the same problem as me, Firebase is looking into it and it seems it's a bug only present on certain devices and emulators. They are not quite sure where it's coming from but trying to find out.

When they give me more information, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Anything come of this? I just ran into it.

Comment: Not really, I created a workaround which fixes the issue in my situation. I just added a boolean to my object which tracks if the change was local. It is not written to the firestore and is set to false again when the listener is called for the first time. Not foolproof, but seems to be working for now. Official answer from Firebase support: Since this can be considered as an issue, it will be added to the next development cycle, based on the priority and urgency assigned. Thanks for all the effort here, and keep an eye on the release notes for more updates.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to the bug you found/filed with Firebase?

Comment: @kmell96 I would not mind, however I have filed a support request via email which was escalated to a bug report. So I don't have any publicly available info. I searched for a bug tracker and it seems there is none for Firebase. The one I found (issuetracker.google.com) does not have any information for the reference/case numbers I have. I don't think this has high priority for Google since there are few reports about this issue.