# document.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites() shows true because of data not storing in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to store `RIDE_KEY` in Firebase it is not storing because of that `pendingWrites` shows true. If pending writes are false it is storing `RIDE_KEY` in Firebase but it's not storing for my fifth time. What is the problem here? So can you give me a solution to this issue? I tried but it's showing the same `pendingwrites` shows true but I need false.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("RIDE_KEY").document(mPresenter.ride_key());
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        assert document != null;
        if (!document.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()) {
            //
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet?

Comment: yes it connected

Comment: You may profit from taking a look at a comment to the answer to the [Firestore's hasPendingWrites() returns false on deleted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884508/firestores-haspendingwrites-returns-false-on-deleted-document) question. This comment provides a workaround that may be applicable in your case. There is an issue being under consideration right now, related to the hasPendingWrites() method.